# How to avoid UnicodeEncodeError while printing contents of a file

Tags: unicode, python-3.5

Here's a function that converts a textfile into a list of tokens.

```
def tokenizeFile(TextFile):
    text_string = TextFile.lower()
    result=""
    punct = string.punctuation;
    for char in range (0,len(text_string)):
        if(text_string[char] in punct):
            if(text_string[char-1].isdigit()):
                 result += text_string[char]
        if(text_string[char] not in punct):
            result += text_string[char]
    token = (result.split())
    return token
```

I want to print this list of tokens but on running the following program :-

```
txt = open("test.txt",encoding = 'utf-8')
text = txt.read()    
token = tokenizeFile(text)
print(token)
```

I get the UnicodeEncodeError.From what I have researched, I know you have to explicitly tell python by .encode() method. I am a beginner at python. I just don't know how to implement that. Kindly help me!
From what I have done till now is opening another file in write mode using the same encoding and write into that text file. The program shows no error but I want the program to print out tokens. Please help me here!

Comment: You haven't shown *where* the error occurs.  I can guess, but shouldn't have to.  That said, you can only print characters supported by your terminal encoding without additional help.  The Windows console doesn't support UTF-8 well. Use an IDE that supports UTF-8 encoding in its output window.

Comment: @MarkTolonen the upcoming Python 3.6 bypasses byte-based I/O on the Windows console and uses the native interface, which is UTF-16. No more problems writing Unicode to the console!

Comment: @MarkRansom No, then the reason why it won't work will be the font :)  I did notice that Windows 10 allows more fonts, including Asian...at least on my system where I have the Chinese IME enabled.  We'll just have a new set of problems.

Comment: @MarkTolonen but at least that won't be Python's fault. It'll be a lot easier to explain. I'm quite looking forward to it, it's way overdue.

Comment: The UnicodeEncodeError comes when I try to print the token list ,("print(token)"), Although if I just pass the token list on the interpreter, it shows no error. I t only shows error while printing it out. Any suggestions??